# changing contact joint parameters during simulation

Tags: gazebo, contact, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to change the **contact joint parameters** of a model / link after it is loaded in Gazebo, from a plugin.

The idea is that I am spawning a model with a lot of sphere links, which act like a fluid.
After a while I want to change the **contact joint parameters** values so that the links act like a rigid body.

The contact joint parameters are something like this at the **beginning**:

```
<contact>
  <ode soft_cfm='100.0' soft_erp='100.0' kp='1000000.0' kd='1000000.0' max_vel='100.0' min_depth='0.001'/>
</contact>
```

So, is there a way to modify them from a plugin? (I have the plugin made, I can access everything in the world). I know that these joints are created only when contacts occur between links. That is why I suppose I cannot access them with something like:

this->my_model->getJoint(..);

Any suggestions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/360/changing-contact-joint-parameters-during-simulation/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi @AndreiHaidu, I create a plugin that modifies the properties at runtime. I don't know if is the best approach but I think that will help you.

[plugin.h](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13610557534835179.h)

[plugin.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13610556638620614.cpp)

[Test.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/13610555695819705.world)

After compile you and run the gazebo world you should see a box that will be pushed from left to right by a small speed. There is some friction between box and ground plane, so the box starts to inclinate. About five seconds before the simulation is started, the mu (friction) coefficients are changed by plugin (decreasing) and the box will slip. Five seconds later the mu coefficients are changed by plugin (increasing) and the box starts to inclinate again, and so on...

I hope that it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-02-16**:
Hi, thanks for the answer, the plugin you wrote looks promising, in my case I will have to change the cfm and erp values, but looking over the API it looks like it is possible.

**Comment by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) on 2013-02-16**:
Yes, I forgot to cite the api: http://gazebosim.org/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1SurfaceParams.html